# Can't get SignalA on android to connect to SignalR backend

Tags: c#, android, signalr

I'm trying to use SignalA (https://github.com/erizet/SignalA) for a small android application.

My SignalR instance is up and looks as follows:

```
namespace SignalRPersistent
{
    public class ChatConnection : PersistentConnection
    {
        protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
        {
            return Connection.Send(connectionId, "Welcome!");
        }

        protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
        {
            return Connection.Broadcast(data);
        }
    }
}
```

my Startup.cs looks like this:

```
namespace SignalRPersistent
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR<ChatConnection>("/echo");
        }
    }
}
```

on the Android side,the relevent code i have is:

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2:45223/echo/";
com.zsoft.signala.Connection con = new com.zsoft.signala.Connection(url, this, new LongPollingTransport()) {

    @Override
    public void OnError(Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "On error: " + exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void OnMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Message: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void OnStateChanged(StateBase oldState, StateBase newState) {

        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "oldState: " + oldState.getState() + " newState: " + newState.getState(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

It seems to see to locate it just fine, but shortly after Disconnects.
 the state changed from Connecting to Disconnected.

what am I missing here?

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Do you get any output in the log?

Comment: Can you please help me out with this. I have downloaded the signala source.jar from maven center but I get error "missing connection class" whereas I can see that the class is present in the .jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was with the applicationhost.config file on my IIS.

I had to change

```
binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:45223:localhost"
```

to:

```
binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:45223:*"
```